# Could not load quick look data for "fileURL" unable to play AVPlayer video because of fileURLWithPath method

Tags: ios, avplayer

I am using Xcode 7 and with quick look feature i encountered this error. It says could not load quick look data for "fileURL" here is my code
// here because of below line @file gets attached to the end of my fileURL like this --

```
 @"http:/example.com/some_clips/SHAINA%20NC%20NEWS%20X%20180516%201657PM.mp4 -- file:///"    see here something file:/// in the end so because of this i am unable to play video.
```

IF i use initWithString and give URL directly then it gives no error please suggest me something to set URL to my player below i have created please read comment in the code also. Do anyone have idea about this.

```
 NSString *localfilepath=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[managedObject valueForKey:@"clip_path"]];  //here i am getting my URL path upto .mp4 but after below line word -- file gets attached to it because of fileURLWithPath method don't know how to convert that 


 NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:localfilepath]; //suggest me this line of code so that i can pass URL to the player here this method is not working


// create a player

player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:fileURL]; //here this fileURL which is going to player is going with that file:/// so giving error and no video runs

AVPlayerViewController *controller = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc] init];

[self addChildViewController:controller];
[self.view addSubview:controller.view];

controller.view.frame = CGRectMake(10,80,300,300);
controller.player = player;
controller.showsPlaybackControls = YES;
[player pause];
```

Comment: `[managedObject valueForKey:@"clip_path"]` class ?

Comment: it is the path of clips in core data from where is am getting  URL's  @Larme

Comment: i have made it :) i found it guys :) just one line code just need to encode that string in  NSUTF8StringEncoding  format i will write the complete solution to this answer

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL URLWithString:localfilepath];
```

Instead of:

```
NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:localfilepath];
```

The [fileURLWithPath:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSURL/fileURLWithPath:) method is used for creating local file (Files that are situated in the device itself) urls.

Comment: thanks for the answer But previously it was like that only but when i used this method the player gets nil value through file URL in debugger under fileURL when we open the client it shows nil @Midhun MP

Comment: @vicky: In that case there is some illegal characters in the url string, that's the reason why you are getting the fileURL as nil.

Comment: Either way above it is not playing video in first way it says nil....and the second is my problem

Comment: @vicky: Why are you calling [player pause] instead of [player play] ?

Comment: that doesn't Matter i'have checked that by keeping both or one it works by using [player play] or [player pause] or both it is working @Midhun MP

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURL/initFileURLWithPath: this initFileURLWithPath is user for creating local file @Midhun MP

Comment: any other way @ Midhun MP

Comment: Can i modify or convert the *fileURL using filePathURL property heres a link --https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSURL/filePathURL  @Midhun MP

Answer (score 0):

i have made it guys :) i found the answer :) This is complete code for playing videos into AVPlayer which are on server

// here i am fetching all the url downloaded from server using core data managed objects

```
NSString *localfilepath=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[managedObject valueForKey:@"clip_path"]];
```

// then on below line i am encoding it into NSUTF8StringEncoding format
      don't forget to do this otherwise video will not play as it wasn't    in my case

```
   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[localfilepath stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

// and below i have assigned url to the player and created the player

```
  player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:url];

AVPlayerViewController *controller = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc] init];

[self addChildViewController:controller];
[self.view addSubview:controller.view];

controller.view.frame = CGRectMake(10,80,300,300);
controller.player = player;
controller.showsPlaybackControls = YES;
//player.closedCaptionDisplayEnabled = NO;
[player pause];
[player play];
```